# Audio input disappears randomly

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, lubuntu, alsa

Same question asked in [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/138073) and [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10251591) and [LinuxQuestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4198440)

I'm running Lubuntu 10.10 on a HP Compaq nx6325. I use it to digitize tape records - connecting the tape deck's headphone output to the notebook's microphone input. Audacity then records the 45 minutes of sound.
However, from time to time, audio input just disappears. There is no data incoming; instead of audacity recording silence, the track cursor completely stops in its way. When using gnome-sound-recorder, the clock counter stays greyed out even though I start recording. Issuing

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

fixes things again. The system logs show little useful, although I can post the more relevant parts if asked.
Does alsa (or pulseaudio) have some kind of log somewhere? Can I make one? Is there any other or better way to find the problem?

Comment: are you playing back the audio as your record? audacity can misbehave if that option is enabled.

Comment: Indeed, if recording is played back in audacity then even alsa force-reload doesn't help. However, recording playback is disabled and input disappears only occasionally. Also, if this was a problem in audacity, then gnome-sound-recorder would work.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: yes, gave up a long time ago.

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.